# Detecting and removing corrupt null-filled files efficiently and reliably

Tags: bash, unix, filesystems

### Portable Shell Function / Script to check for files that are full of null bytes

I've thought about looking at file signatures, magic bytes, etc, but I don't want to use any indirect assumptions (other than say, a known mechanism, such as hexdump output below)

### This is what i use now:

```
#!/bin/bash 

file="$1" 
bail () { 
    >&2 echo "$file doesn't exist" 
    exit 1 
} 

[ -f "$1" ] ; [[ "$?" != 0 ]] && bail                     # Check valid filename
result="$(head -c4 "$file" | hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"')"   
if [ "$result" == "0000" ] || [ "$result" == "00000000" ] # Get first 4 bytes as pre-condition
    then                                                                                                    # Check for large contiguous blocks of null 
        head -c10000 "$file" | hexdump | \
        if [[ "$(wc -l <<<"$(cat -)")" -le 4 ]]           # By virtue of pre-condition, all output must be null
        then 
            exit 2                                        # Exit Codes
         else 
            exit 0                                         # 0: File is good
        fi                                                 # 1: Validation error
    else                                                   # 2: File is cactus
        exit 0
fi
```

The idea is that:

- Check first 4 bytes as pre-condition
- Use `hexdump` without `-v` to group multiple sets of the pre-condition (null bytes)
- Use `head -c1K` to limit excessive output internally
- Use `wc -l` check for <=4 lines.  Any more would indicate a change from null.

And the reason for some of the wacky and indirect syntax, is because `bash` on some machines gives me this `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`, and I've found this to get around it.

Iterating a file through the above seems slow, but usuable for the time being:

```
real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.021s
```

## Is there a better and more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Why would you have large, corrupt files full of null bytes? It isn't a common problem, is it? Maybe use `grep -m1` to search for and stop at first non-null byte.

Comment: It is well explained in this cross site dupe [How to find files with 100% NUL characters in their contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58975/112235)

Comment: @MarkSetchell but files can have legitimate null bytes in them.

Comment: Thanks @Inian - but some of these types of solutions I have tried.  The key is portability and grep with perl regex is not.  I know while I have some bash 4+ syntax here, but it's a work in progress

Comment: (well ... I don't think `grep -P` is portable anyway... )

Comment: Using `tr` should be portable though @hmedia1

Comment: @Inian Indeed.  Let me do some tests

Comment: @MarkSetchell to answer your first question - I recursively cleared extended attributes on my Dropbox.  This had "Smart Sync" turned on so many files were just placeholders.  I didn't realize this was done via xattributes, i just stupidly assumed it would be done within it's own database (since everything else in the world seems to be happening in there),,, once I cleared the com.dropbox.placeholder through the `-c` option, it was all over - Dropbox rebuilt and overwrote every single placeholder with a full length null version of itself.

Comment: 1.5 million files later

Comment: I was suggesting you look for first **non-null** byte which would mean file isn't entirely composed of null bytes. Then stop on first match to avoid reading rest of file.

Comment: @hmedia1 You should add all clarification or background information to the question instead of writing comments.

Comment: @Bodo, No, it's best I stick to what I need and not bloat the question endlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the systems where you need to do the check support [/dev/zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/zero) then you can test if a file contains only null bytes with:

```
[[ $(LC_ALL=C cmp -- "$file" /dev/zero 2>&1) == 'cmp: EOF on '* ]]
```

- The POSIX manual page for `cmp` ([cmp (The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html)) gives a precise specification for the STDERR output in the POSIX locale.  `LC_ALL=C` forces `cmp` to use the POSIX [Locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html), so the comparison with `'cmp: EOF on '*` will work correctly.
- The test is true for empty files.  If you don't want that, you can add a check for non-empty to the test: `[[ -s $file && ... ]]`.
- The `--` in the `cmp` command arguments protects against files with names starting with `-` being treated as `cmp` options.
- Beware very large files, or files that appear to be very large ([sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)).  `cmp` could take a very long time to run on such files.  You might want to consider skipping files that are above a threshold size.

Comment: Unreal.  What a perfect solution.  Thanks